# Cannot Get Hover to Work over a Wrapper Div

Tags: html, css

I need your help.

I can't seem to be able to get the hover working properly over a wrapper/container DIV

CSS:

```
#myhover:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myhover" style="background: #ffffff; 
      width: 177px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #808080;">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input id="refdocs" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 3px; 
                  height: 15px; width: 158px; border: none;" type="text">
    </div>
    <div style="line-height:18px; font-size: 11pt;  color: #779297;">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because inline styles are the most specific in the cascade, they can over-ride things you didn't intend them to. Move your `#myhover` styles into a style sheet then it should work fine.

for example:

```
#myhover {
    background: #ffffff; 
    width: 177px; 
    height: 20px; 
    border: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/va8Bz/**

Comment: Interesting! But it works. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @JohnSmith take a look at [this link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/qt/tipcssinlinesty.htm) to better understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your `style` attribute is overriding your stylesheet selectors. It's more specific.

You have three options here:

1. Move your styles out of the `style` attribute.
2. Move your styles out of the `style` attribute.
3. Add `!important` to the style declarations that should override the ones in your `style` attribute.

I suggest you move your styles out of the `style` attribute into a stylesheet.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7NW9/**

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick all your CSS in a stylesheet instead of using inline styles.

What you're trying to accomplish can be done with less markup too:

```
<div class="container">
    <input class="refdocs" type="text">
    <div class="icon">+</div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS stylesheet:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper {
    float: left;
}

.refdocs {
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    margin: 0;
}

.refdocs:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

**[Here's a working demo](http://jsbin.com/alaveq/1/edit)**

Answer (score -1):

I solved this for you in your previous question:

```
#add {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
#add:hover {
    color: #f00;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kUSBM/

Please respond to the questions or accept answers.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question about hover?

Comment: @JamesMontagne He asked the question previously and I provided the solution **including the hover**. My solution is exactly what he was looking for.

Comment: Really? I get down voted for answering **both** questions? I don't know why I bother trying to help people, especially when they don't even respond to the answers they get.